# How to arrive endtime using starttime and duration in django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model like this;

```
starttime       =     models.TimeField('Show Start Time', )
duration        =     models.DurationField('Duration',)
endtime         =     models.TimeField('Show End Time (Optional)',blank=True, null=True )
```

with the starttime and duration I am trying to arrive the endtime while storing the object;

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    startdelta=timedelta(hours=self.starttime.hour,minutes=self.starttime.minute,seconds=self.starttime.second)
    enddelta =  startdelta + self.duration
    self.endtime = enddelta
    super(Showsets, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Above code throws me error, I want to know how the timefield and duration field works in django also please assist with the ways to query the fields based on starttime or endtime (like objects that starts (starttime) in 30mins from now).

Also curious to know if there are any django-app(add-ons) for time based querying.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Please show the traceback.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this will be a good solution for your circumstance but I normally do something like:

```
start_time = models.TimeField()
end_time = models.TimeField()


def duration(self):
    return self.end_time - self.start_time
```

It seems like a much more concise solution than storing start time with duration and then calculating the end_time on save().

Answer (score 0):

You can combine starttime with today's date and add duration:

```
from datetime import datetime, date

self.endtime = (datetime.combine(date.today(), self.starttime) + self.duration).time()
```